# how to add shortcut to ubuntu taskbar

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, taskbar, cinnamon, launcher

I am using UBUNTU 14.04 with cinnamon desktop. After trying to create a shortcut for a PDF file to Cinnamon's Taskbar, I found maybe I should have searched for a folder containing the Taskbar's configuration information and create a launcher there. And by the way I don't know if I've guessed right or if yes, where would it be!
Would you please help me find a solution to add the shortcut to the pdf file and then place it in the Taskbar? any help and recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using Cinnamon, so I can't check but, here's the general idea.

- Follow [these instructions](http://web.archive.org/web/20150515014821/http://fangel7.tumblr.com:80/post/85322135641/adding-a-custom-application-launcher-in-cinnamon) for adding an application launcher to the taskbar. Ie.

  - If you don't already have a launcher, choose any app in your menu, right click and choose "Add to panel" (you can remove it after the second step).
  - Then right click the launcher area and choose "Add" to pick another application.
- This procedure may work for a file as well as an application.
- If not, one thing you can do is create a custom launcher for that file.

  - In `~/.local/share/applications/`, create a new file called, for example `launch-myPDF.desktop` (where `myPDF` is the name of the file).
  - Save the following text in the file.

    ```
      [Desktop Entry]
      Exec=/usr/bin/nemo myPDF.pdf
      Icon=/usr/share/icons/myicon.png
      Name=Launch myPDF
      Path=/path/to/myPDF
    ```

  where each entry is edited appropriately. `Exec=` should contain a command that launches the file you want to pin in whatever application you want it to open in.

  - If you choose `Add` from the launcher and choose that desktop file, you'll add a custom launcher for your file.

There may be a way to pin files directly, but if not, the above procedure is a workaround.

Comment: Expired tumblr link.

Comment: @maciejwww: thanks, replaced with archive.org link.